# Compiling Java Source Files to Native Code

Tags: java, native, launch4j, jsmooth

I need to compile a Java Project into native code.

The target machine cannot run Java in any way (customer preference).

I have perviously successfully compiled the Application to an executable using Launch4J and Jsmooth, respectively. However, bundling the JRE with the application is not an option here.

What are my options?

Comment: [GraalVM `native-image`](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/native-image/), or [GCJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java) (which is quite long in the tooth).

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that [GraalVM has some limitations](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/native-image/#aot-compilation-limitations).

Comment: Thanks Elliott, Graal looks promising.